Why does Aemond sleep in the arms of an older woman in "House of the Dragon"?
In the House of the Dragon series (season 2, episode 2), why is Aemond seen sleeping in the arms of a significantly older woman in such an intimate manner? What emotional or psychological need might be driving this behavior?

Aemond Targaryen's relationship with older women has its roots in the source material, George R.R. Martin's Fire & Blood. In the book, Aemond develops a relationship with Alys Rivers, an older woman who becomes a key player for the Greens during the Dance of the Dragons. (While Alys Rivers appeared in Season 2, this particular plot point wasn't included.)
As for the scene in Episode 2, where Aemond is seen in an intimate embrace with an older woman in a brothel, there are a few possible explanations.
This scene likely alludes to Aemond's relationship with Alys Rivers (in the book), hinting at his preference for mature women. It also reflects Aemond's strained relationship with his mother, Alicent. She blames him for starting the war by killing Prince Lucerys Velaryon, as Aemond himself points out:

She blames me for starting this war after she plotted with my father's council to usurp his throne.

Given this tension with his mother, Aemond might be seeking out a form of maternal comfort and affection, especially since he's also grappling with guilt over being the intended target of Blood and Cheese's attack, which tragically resulted in his nephew's death instead.
Interestingly, this behavior is not unique in the world of A Song of Ice and Fire. In the books, some of the Unsullied are known to visit brothels simply to be held and comforted by women, rather than for sexual services.

It is a common scene in this show House of the Dragon, from both the Blacks and the Greens, high-born show little emotion and always put political outcome over personal feelings.
Born in a royal family does have lots of benefits as well as hidden costs.
We have seen how the father-daughter relationship plays out between Alicent and her dad. It is more about politics and power rather than personal feelings.
I personally believe Aemond sleeping in the arms of an older woman indicates that he has some emotional trauma from his mom during his upbringing, possibly due to being held to a high standard all the time, could not express his feelings truthfully, being told to hide true feelings in front of people especially to these who are close and etc.
This older woman, Aemond is completely naked, fully exposing himself both physically and emotionally; he also removes his eye-patch, showing the scar to her as well. Perhaps to Aemond, this is the place and time to be a normal person, it is OK to show his weaknesses and a more "human" side.

+1 to mommy issues being reason for attraction to older women.
